# How to run Progress Dialog on UI thread and make the progress bar updated

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, progress-bar

I have a Progress Dialog that runs in the end of the wizard. The operation, that takes a lot of time must be done on UI thread. Is it some way to have a progress bar updated while operation is in progress?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set `fork` parameter in a call to run to `false`
2. Keep 'pumping' the UI events - see `Display::readAndDispatch` for details.

Are you sure this should be done in UI thread? In most cases it is much easier to do in non-UI thread eventually offloading UI stuff with `Display::asyncExec` or `Display::syncExec`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, I'm sure that I must to complete my job on UI thread

Answer (score 0):

You can try `dlg.paintAll(dlg.getGraphics());`, but the problem with refreshing manually is that the dialog only refreshes at given intervalls, when you call it. So when the user clicks some other window to the front and want to check later how far it progressed, he will not see it until the next refresh happens.

Why can't you execute the code in a thread?  You create the ProgressDialog as modal, then you start the worker thread and after executing it, you set the progress to visible. The you can update it in the thread and also close it in the thread. The main thread will block until the worker is done and also stays visible.